# Logon Error : Catastrophic failure(Exception from HRESULT : 0x8000FFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I get the error message below when i start my application without break points. As soon as i put a break point and hover over variables then i don't get it. I also get the error when i launch the application(Windows Forms) via exe in debug folder. The error message occurs when i try to access information from app config. This error started appearing as soon as i upgraded .net framework from 3.5 to 4.6.2 on my app. Please check my code below:

```
 -- Main form.
   Impersonator.StartImpersonation()

   Dim Login As New frmLogin()  --main form calls frmLogin
   Login.Owner = Me
   Login.ShowDialog()
   Login.Dispose()


   --frmLogin on load

     Private Sub OnLoad()

            If My.Settings.Test = "Y" Then  'breaks here. but if i over over My.Settings.Test it doesnt break
                _DSN = My.Settings.ConfigTest
            Else
                _DSN = My.Settings.ConfigLive
            End If

        End Sub 'GetDSN
```

What could be the issue? I'm using visual studio 2017.

[image]

Here is the stack trace of the error :

```
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal.System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigurationManagerInternal.get_ExeProductName()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Initializer()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.CreateSetting(PropertyInfo propInfo)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Properties()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's very hard to know what's wrong. A quick google of the error seems to imply this is an SQL Server error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/831715/catastrophic-failure-error-message-when-you-use-the-sql-server-login-d

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by Impersonator.StartImpersonation() . I removed Impersonator.StartImpersonation() line and every worked fine. It seems like .Net 3.5 supported Impersonator.StartImpersonation() without any issues.